# How do I enable the BuildBundlerMinifier extension for a desktop application in VS2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am attempting to use the BuildBundlerMinifier Visual Studio extension by Mads Kristensen. My use case is unusual: I have a desktop application that uses .html files as help/documentation and I want to minify the associated .css and .js files as part of the build process.

I installed the extension via Nuget, no errors.

The docs say that I can right-click on a file in the Solution Explorer to see a "Bundler & Minifier" command with several subcommands. I do not see that entry in the context menu.

The docs also say that installing the extension in a project will add a bundleconfig.json file to the project. That file was not added.

I suspect one of two problems:

1 - I neglected to install something or configure something required by BuildBundlerMinifier.

2 - BuildBundlerMinifier is limited to Visual Studio web projects.

Have I missed a step required to use the extension? Will the extension work with any VS project?

Comment: i'm not seeing it either...

Comment: Have you solved it? I've just installed the same package in VS 2017 and can't see the bundleconfig.json either... @Johnny

Comment: @nickornotto - No, never solved it. It's buried in a comment below, but after not getting an answer here, I went a different route and so I gave up trying to get the extension to work.

Comment: @Johny what route did you go? How are you minifying?

Answer (score 4):

Apologies for raising this old question from the dead, but it could be because in order to see the context menu with Bundler & Minifier, you need to install the Visual Studio extension, not just the Nuget package.

In Visual Studio 2019 I go to the Extensions menu, and then manage extensions, and search for "bundle".

Answer (score 0):

You have to right click on bundleconfig.json then Bundle & Minifier to be able to select this option.

Comment: My project does not contain bundleconfig.json, so there is nothing to right-click on. After not getting an answer here, I went a different route and so I gave up trying to get the extension to work.